# VueJS is updating another element on an event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have just started learning VueJS and while writing some code I noticed that another HTML element was getting updated on event fire.

app.js

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return {
            name: "Name",
            age: 21,
            url: "",
            input_data: "",
        }   
    },
    methods: {
        getRandom(){
            return Math.random();
        },
        setText(event){
            this.input_data = event.target.value;
        },
    }
}).mount('#assignment');
```

index.html

```
<section id="assignment">
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>

      <input type="text" v-on:input="setText($event)" />
      <p>{{input_data}}</p>

      <p>{{age}}</p>

      <p>{{age+5}}</p>

      <p>Favorite Number: {{getRandom()}}</p>
      <div>
        <img v-bind:src="url" />
      </div>

</section>
```

Whenever I enter text in the input field it does update

tag with {{input_data}} but it also updates the Favorite Number section which is not as expected.  Does anyone know why is this happening?

I'm using latest version of Vue(3.0.5) from CDN

Thanks,

-Atharva

Answer (score 4):

Alireza already provided a workaround/solution but here comes the explaination.

When your Vue app loads it reads the template you have provided and replaces all the {{tags}} with the values. To get the value of {{getRandom()}} it calls the method getRandom().

Whenever any of the underlying values changes Vue will repeat this process. Now you see the new values on your screen. This is what they mean with Vue's reactivity.

Now because you changed input_data the template gets reevaluated, which again calls the getRandom() function. This is why that value 'unexpectedly' changed when you inputted some text.

Comment: You could also create another property `favoriteNumber` within `data()`, setting it in `mounted()`, which will cause it only to execute once regardless of updates to the vDOM.

Comment: @Jousha I understand that when state of a variable is changed Vue re-renders that app...but when I inspected it I developer console only these two were re-rendered not age and age+5.  Follow up: is it because the way vue app object stores returned value ie values not stored in variable ?

Comment: Ok, Vue re-evaluates the template and shows you the 'current state' of your app. age and age+5 do get taken into account (are re-evaluated) but since their values/outcomes haven't changed there is no difference to show..  And yes for getRandom() it displays the return value but it does not store it anywhere indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:
vuejs use virtual DOM to re-rendering components when data changes, so when you use a method like that in your code, it runs *getRandom()* because of changing *input_data*.

you must put

```
getRandom(){
            return Math.random();
        },
```

in computed

```
computed:{
    getRandom(){
                return Math.random();
            },
},
methods: {

    setText(event){
        this.input_data = event.target.value;
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because when you change component data (state), the component will be rerendered, And when component rerendered your **getRandom()**  method will execute again and generate new random number.

In your case rerendering happens because you change the component data:

```js
this.input_data = event.target.value;
```

If you want to prevent this behavior, you should put your **getRandom()** function in **computed** instead of methods.